# Consufused when choice XNA for game in C#

Tags: c#, xna, xna-4.0

I have 1 problem, and I want to consult with people.
I have started to do game with XNA in C#, but I don't know, in the future, XNA has also developed.
Thanks all.

Comment: Don't use XNA for new stuff. Go to SharpDX, Unity3D or MonoGame, something that is actively developed and supported.

Comment: thanks you so much, i will think and give decision for my question.
may be, i will choice unity to developed. :)

Comment: XNA is no longer being supported by Microsoft. You can use Monogame which runs over XNA, or an engine such as Unity3D or Unreal.

Comment: As Nahuel mentioned, you might want to look into middleware products such as Unity3D or Unreal4 (sadly U4 is c++ only).  Unity3D provides out-of-the-box physics; networking; path-AI; designers; scene editing; asset management - all things base XNA/MonoGame do not provide.  Without losing the ability to **program in c#** in Unity3D I might add

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you like using XNA to develop games, but want a currently supported library with a decently supportive community, I would check out MonoGame. They're basically the same tool, with slight differences but with the same basic functionality.

[Here is the site.](http://www.monogame.net/)

From the site:

> MonoGame is an Open Source implementation of the Microsoft XNA 4 Framework. Our goal is to allow XNA developers on Xbox 360, Windows & Windows Phone to port their games to the iOS, Android, Mac OS X, Linux and Windows 8 Metro. PlayStation Mobile, Raspberry PI, and PlayStation 4 platforms are currently in progress.

Comment: Also, MonoGame is currently on GitHub, so if you find it interesting, you can be active in its development.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I will try it, and find my favorite ^_^